# Twitter Bootstrap Modal Window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

On clicking a Button i want to show a Modal Window.

This is what i have implemented.

```
<a class="btn addIdeaBtn" data-toggle="modal" href="#addIdea" >Launch Modal</a> 
<!-- Model Window
    ================================================== --> 
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="addIdea">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Add Idea</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <textarea id="addIdeaPopUp" class="tinymce" name="" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="home.html" class="btn">Close</a> <a href="home.html" class="btn btn-primary">Add Idea</a> </div>
</div>
```

When i click the Button the modal window appears and then  vanishes :P

> http://mink7.com/projects/cmrc/idea_exchange.html

The button is at the bottom of the screen to the left sticking as a footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the `in` class from your modal. The JS automatically toggles between `hide` and `in`. Since your button is set to toggle the modal, it disappears, because it believes it is visible.

Meaning: `<div class="modal hide fade" id="addIdea">`

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why it is happening without seeing more source code... but:
Adding the class "tinymce" to your text area is what is causing the window to vanish.

Something with tinymce must be conflicting with bootstrap.

You may need to manually initialize bootstraps modal window or be careful about how tinymce is initializing itself.

Hopefully this is enough to get you down the right path.

Comment: thats just a class. we havent included TunyMCE into the project yet.